# Metadata rejected because I didn't give them a test account, but its not something I can do?

Tags: ios, ios7, metadata

> We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because
>   we need a demo account to fully access your app features.
>
> Please provide demo account details in the Review Notes section of the
>   Version Information for your app. Please ensure that the information
>   you provide includes any data necessary to demonstrate the
>   functionality of your app features.
>
> Specifically, upon review of your application we have found that the
>   application requires a username/password to access full functionality.

My app acts as a reference to school sites. There are a bunch of buttons that take the user to different school sites like their school mail, marks, etc. I cannot just create a demo school account for them (each student gets one account when they enter the university). You cannot just create a new login at will. I'm not exactly comfortable giving them my own school account for them to do the testing on. Like I don't want them logging into my mail. What can I do?

Comment: You need to create a demo account so Apple can log in and test your app. No demo account, no app approval. How do you expect Apple to test your app if they can't use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get such an app through App Review is to somehow provide a test account. Contact your school, if need be. Apple can't very well review apps if they can't use them.